# How can I forward bash/zsh arguments to another shell

Tags: bash, quotes, zsh

I'm working on a system with a lot of tcsh configuration scripts, requiring me to run most programs through tcsh. I've attempted to make this easy for myself by adding this to my `~/.zshrc`:

```
# run command in tcsh
function t() {
    tcsh -c "$@"
}
```

This works for something like `t ls`, but fails for `t ls -l`, which gives the error `` Unknown option: `-l' Usage: tcsh ... ``, and is clearly passing `-l` as an argument to `tcsh`, not to `ls`.

How can I quote the string passed in `$@`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8723305/102441) had what I needed:

```
# run command in tcsh
function t() {
    C=''
    for i in "$@"; do
        C="$C \"${i//\"/\\\"}\""
    done;
    tcsh -c "$C"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Zsh has a special option for this (not bash): `${(q)}`:

```
tcsh -c "${(j. .)${(q)@}}"
```

. First (`${(q)@}`) escapes all characters in the `$@` array items that have special meaning, second (`${(j. .)…}`) joins the array into one string.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work

```
function t {
  tcsh -c "$*"
}
```

and is a whole lot shorter than what you found in the other answer ;-)

[edit:]

ok, if you really want to get perverse with quotes... give up the function and just use an alias (which is probably a better idea anyway)

```
alias t='tcsh -c'
```

[edit2:] Here is a good and to the point discussion of the different ways to quote parameters in Zsh http://zshwiki.org/home/scripting/args

Comment: Thanks! What does `$*` do that `$@` doesn't?

Comment: Nevermind, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3990540/102441) answered my question.

Comment: Does this work properly even for arguments containing spaces? e.g. `t ls -l "ab cd"`?