# Why can't I echo the characters #! in a string in bash?

Tags: bash

I had a tiny bash script that is supposed to move to my home directory, make a file, echo some junk onto it, and make it executable. This is what it looked like:

```
cd ; touch tor.sh; echo "#!/bin/bash\n/usr/local/bin/tor" >> tor.sh; chmod +x tor.sh
```

But this kept breaking at the echo, complaining about "event not found" ? For some reason I decided to try this and it worked:

```
cd ; touch tor.sh; echo -e "\x23\x21/bin/bash\n/usr/local/bin/tor" >> tor.sh; chmod +x tor.sh
```

Why did I have to replace those two characters (the shebang?) with hex and a -e? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug and it has nothing to do with the shebang, just the exclamation point.

```
Enclosing  characters  in double quotes preserves the literal value of
all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \,  and,
when  history expansion is enabled, !.
```

So either escape it, use single quotes, or turn off history expansion.

e.g.

```
> echo "How dare you put an '!' in this string?"
bash: !: event not found
> set +o histexpand
> echo "How dare you put an '!' in this string?"
How dare you put an '!' in this string?
```

Comment: You answered explained the cause of my problem in the most straightforward way, and that is the part I cared more about. But if I could, I'd also accept Red Cricket's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use single quotes to prevent string extrapolation:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/local/bin/tor'
```

Or you might escape shebang:

```
echo "#\!/bin/bash\n/usr/local/bin/tor"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "\", like:

```
echo \#\!/whatever > test
```

Answer (score 1):

try `'`'s instead of `"`'s like this ...

```
$ echo '#!/bin/bash' > thing.sh
$ cat thing.sh
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score -1):

Two reasons:

One, the difference in behavior between double and single-quoted strings.

`"#!/bin/bash\n/usr/local/bin/tor"` is "expanded" — that is, the commands within quotes here will be executed first.

Thus,
 `echo "$(echo foo)" > file` puts 'foo' in `file`, while
 `echo '$(echo foo)' > file` puts
'$(echo foo)' in `file`.

"#!" is a comment, and this does not occur in other shells. If it begins a file (as a shebang), POSIX specifies that this is undefined behavior; but there's no reason why this should be happening here.

Comment: Here is some more advanced discussion of the [treatment and effect of string expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448407/bash-script-to-receive-and-repass-quoted-parameters).

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on someone else's answer, so I guess I'll put this here: I stand by calling this a bug. Nowhere [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) is that behavior specified; this cannot be reproduced in any other shell (dash ksh mksh pdksh yash). If it is a bashism, this should be disabled when invoked with `bash --posix`.

Comment: So everything that can't be reproduced in other shells is a bug?

Comment: I have no interest in engaging in a flame war with you, bro. Of course not; its a bug to claim to be implementing a standard, particularly in a strictly compliant mode, to introduce a different and incompatible behavior (plus, have no documentation for this deviation).

Comment: Where do you think think the quote in my answer comes from?

Comment: The bash documentation website.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

Comment: And also now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496049/what-is-the-intended-effective-ordering-of-set-o-options-in-bash-does-histe