# What is the intended effective ordering of `set -o` options in bash? Does `histexpand` trump `posix`?

Tags: bash, set, posix, standards, sh

I attempted to answer a question a couple hours ago which I believed revealed a somewhat obscure bug in [bash POSIX mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html). I was hastily and *vehemently* told this was not so. The contradicting answer, which explicitly says this is *not* a bug, was selected as the correct answer.

So I've been combing over the bash documentation, and I'm still coming away with very much the same impression, so I thought I should ask.

My (alleged) bug:

`set -o histexpand` (which is typically implicit)
`set -o posix`
`echo "#!/"`

Should, well, echo `#!/`. (It does in any other shell). But in bash it instead
prints to standard output

`!/: event not found`

And then returns 0.

So it would seem to me that bash's implicit `set -o histexpand` is in rare cases in contravention of the POSIX standard, and does not make way for `set -o posix`.

The documentation for [`set -o posix`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) reads:

`Change the behavior of Bash where the default operation differs from the POSIX standard ... This is intended to make Bash behave as a strict superset of that standard.`

And I've always thought that this meant that this option should supersede other `set` options when they contradict? 
This doesn't appear to be one of the [48 enumerated differences](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html) either.

Is this not the case? What am I missing?

Comment: If you're curious, like me, the "other question" is apparently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494213/why-cant-i-echo-the-characters-in-a-string-in-bash/21494334#21494334

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Bash POSIX Mode reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html) I *would* expect the behaviour you're seeing - it doesn't say anywhere on that list that history numbers (outside of `PS1` and `PS2` expansions) will be treated differently with `posix` set. Also, since others said it was not a bug I guess the meaning of "superset" is that *as long as no Bash-specific settings are in place* the shell will behave according to the POSIX standard.

Interestingly, even if you run `bash --noprofile --norc --posix` some Bash-specific settings are on by default:

```
bash-4.2$ set -o | grep 'on$'
braceexpand     on
emacs           on
hashall         on
histexpand      on
history         on
interactive-comments    on
monitor         on
posix           on
```

None of these are mentioned in the [POSIX Shell Command Language documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) (I looked up their shorthands in `man bash` first), and **`interactive-comments` is not mentioned anywhere**.

Comment: Right. Which to be explicit, makes it a subset, not a superset, in English or mathematics/logic as typically understood.

Apparently, "interactive-comments" are not things (which was my first guess).
The option apparently means "allow parsing through unquoted hash symbols encountered on the command line."

Answer (score -1):

To turn off history expansion from "!" tokens, use

```
set +o histexpand
```

You instead had a "-o"
Counter-intuitively, "+o" turns histexpand OFF.

Comment: The OP's intent was not to turn history expansion _off_, it was to explicitly turn it _on_ in order to see if a subsequent `set -o posix` would implicitly turn it off.