# grep tries to read from a file instead of through pipe when passing function arguments with a space

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a function that will find all processes by name and then let you send signals to them one by one. Here is the smallest part of code that I can't get to work correctly:

```
ps -ef | grep "$@"
```

If I used

```
ab cd
```

as the input to the function, I'd like it to generate

```
ps -ef | grep "ab cd"
```

but instead it generates

```
ps -ef | grep ab cd
```

which looks for 'ab' in the file 'cd'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `"$*"`, not `"$@"`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3990540/240443) goes into details, but basically `"$@"` quotes each parameter individually, while `"$*"` quotes the whole mess. So, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"ab" "cd"`; `"$*"` is equivalent to `"ab cd"`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried so hard to search for the proper stack overflow response (I knew someone must have asked something like this before) but I couldn't find it.