# How to use a string variable as an operator?

Tags: bash, shell, operators

I would like to use a string as an operator:

```
if [[ "$show_output" = "yes" ]]; then
    redirect_cmd_str=' 2>&1 | tee -a'
else
    redirect_cmd_str=' &>>'
fi
$my_command $redirect_cmd_str $my_log
```

Is it possible in shell/bash?

Answer (score 5):

Shell syntax doesn't support this kind of usage. It's possible to achieve with `eval` but I recommend you [avoid `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead). Using it is a bad habit that can very easily lead to exploitable holes. From a security perspective it's very, very tricky to use `eval` safely.

Rather than storing code in a *variable*, a better tool for the job is a *function*:

```
maybe_show() {
    if [[ $show_output = yes ]]; then
        "$@" 2>&1 | tee -a "$my_log"
    else
        "$@" &>> "$my_log"
    fi
}
```

Then you simply prepend any command with the function name:

```
maybe_show my_command arg1 arg2 arg3
```

(`$my_command` shouldn't be a variable either. It can also be a function if it does something dynamic.)

Comment: i like your solution, but could you add example on how i can add ```$show_output``` and ```$my_log``` as arguments?  i find it dirty to change variable before function call, but maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: and why do you use ```"$@"``` instead of ```$@``` ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3990540/68587): "When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" ...`"

Comment: Handling arguments in a function is the same as handling them in a script. They use the same syntax & tricks. So you can refer to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-a-bash-script) for a guide on argument handling.

Answer (score 0):

There is the eval solution:

```
eval "$my_command $redirect_cmd_str $my_log"
```

but this is not the best solution as comments suggest.

Comment: [be careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead) when using `eval` ...